# Visual Studio code : Issue loading Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, lwc

I am using visual studio code to do my LWC change and it takes at lest 5 minutes to load those extensions. Some times it fails outright and would not let me run commends.

Is there an option to force run extensions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to force run extensions in VSCode. It is likely that your hardware and system configuration is not capable of running your program quickly. Consider editing your question to include your computer specs.

While [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) does require better hardware than VSCode, consider trying that IDE for LWC instead in case it is a VSCode issue and not your hardware.

Comment: My system is a second Gen Surface  book 2 with Core i7 8650U and 8GB DDR4.

Comment: it sounds quite capable of handling visual studio code. i would only recommend you to reinstall vscode and try running it with no other programs open— see if that makes a difference. which extensions is vscode using?